# malloc() crashes, saying corrupted double-linked list

Tags: c, malloc

**Edit** Full source is here:

http://code.seanwoods.com/reynard.fossil.cgi/artifact/0cc9cbfbe021c2ba86dcb4d0cf6ada52f0a80063

Calling program here:

http://code.seanwoods.com/reynard.fossil.cgi/artifact/891405e62c95349aaf461dfb8ba82259f77fac9b

I've got a relatively simple memory allocation that's failing.  The application is not particularly complicated although it does allocate memory in a few places.  It's C, not C++.  I'm positive this is an issue *allocating* memory, not *freeing* memory.

Here's the code:

```
printf(":2 %d %d\n", initial_len, initial_len * sizeof(char));
o->data = (char*) malloc(initial_len * sizeof(char));
printf(":3 \n");
```

Upon execution, I get:

```
:1
:2 1024 1024
*** glibc detected *** ./menv: corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000001d14400 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76d76)[0x7f680cfc4d76]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x771ed)[0x7f680cfc51ed]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x794d4)[0x7f680cfc74d4]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x70)[0x7f680cfc9b90]
./menv[0x403971]
./menv[0x40391d]
./menv[0x4030ec]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7f680cf6cead]
./menv[0x401369]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00405000 r-xp 00000000 08:03 2621441                            /home/swoods/code/reynard/modules/stdlib/menv
00605000-00606000 rw-p 00005000 08:03 2621441                            /home/swoods/code/reynard/modules/stdlib/menv
00606000-00706000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
01cfd000-01d3d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f6808000000-7f6808021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6808021000-7f680c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f680cd38000-7f680cd4d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10354962                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f680cd4d000-7f680cf4d000 ---p 00015000 08:05 10354962                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f680cf4d000-7f680cf4e000 rw-p 00015000 08:05 10354962                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f680cf4e000-7f680d0ce000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10354980                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f680d0ce000-7f680d2ce000 ---p 00180000 08:05 10354980                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f680d2ce000-7f680d2d2000 r--p 00180000 08:05 10354980                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f680d2d2000-7f680d2d3000 rw-p 00184000 08:05 10354980                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.13.so
7f680d2d3000-7f680d2d8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f680d2d8000-7f680d2da000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10354973                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f680d2da000-7f680d4da000 ---p 00002000 08:05 10354973                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f680d4da000-7f680d4db000 r--p 00002000 08:05 10354973                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f680d4db000-7f680d4dc000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 10354973                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.13.so
7f680d4dc000-7f680d4fc000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10354984                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7f680d6df000-7f680d6e2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f680d6f8000-7f680d6fb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f680d6fb000-7f680d6fc000 r--p 0001f000 08:05 10354984                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7f680d6fc000-7f680d6fd000 rw-p 00020000 08:05 10354984                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so
7f680d6fd000-7f680d6fe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffff3bd6000-7ffff3bf7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffff3bff000-7ffff3c00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

- The code compiles without issue.
- When I run it "standalone," it crashes with the error above.  I see `:2` but I don't see
  `:3`, which tells me it's an error *within malloc*.  (I hope I'm wrong.)
- When I run the same binary through `valgrind`, it works as expected.
- It does not appear to be an issue with the variable declaration `o->data`, which is a
  `char*`.  If I declare `char* A; A =` instead of `o->data =` it still crashes.

I would greatly appreciate any ideas as to how to troubleshoot/why this happens.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `*o` object allocated?

Comment: You'll need to provide a SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Need to see a full, compilable example as others have said, but in the meantime, don't cast the return from `malloc()`, and don't use `sizeof(char)` since it's always `1`.

Comment: Your error is presumably caused by heap corruption.  So the error in your code is before the call to `malloc` you've posted.  This is why you're being asked to show more code.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - I guess I was being overly cautious with `sizeof()`.  I know you're supposed to use that when using types that could be different across architectures (like `int`) so I guess I was being overly cautious.

@VaughnCato This is part of a larger project that could be a bit hard to follow, but I've posted links to my source repository in the original post.  Thanks!

Comment: Haven't nailed down your problem, but couple of random observations: (1) You don't seem to `#include <stdlib.h>`, I don't know what `zstring.h` includes, but you need this for `malloc()`, and not casting the return would probably warn you about this. (2) Your initialization functions `return 0` on failure, but your `main()` function ignores that, and just carries on regardless.

Comment: I notice you're on a 64 bit system, so if you don't `#include <stdlib.h>`, then `malloc()` is likely to return an implicit `int`, which is going to give you problems if you're on a system with 32 bit `int`s and 64 bit pointers. Exactly the kind of reason why you shouldn't cast the return from `malloc()`.

Comment: Thanks, @PaulGriffiths, for your help/advice.  `<stdlib.h>` is included in `"zstring.h"`, I suppose for the sake of clarity and correctness I should explicitly include it in the C source file.

Answer (score 18):

So, I think I found it.  We may need to file this under "Sean needs to learn basic Valgrind skills."  Here's how I solved it for any future observers.

1. Okay, we're dealing with a really strange error thrown by a tried and tested library
   function, so it must be something specific to my setup.  The algorithm is the same,
   so it must be the *data*.
2. The dynamic memory implementation has an underlying data structure to track allocated
   memory, which happens to be a doubly linked list -- thus the message.
3. So, there must be a memory operation somewhere that *corrupts* this data structure in
   a subtle way.
4. Okay, what tools do we have at our disposal?  Valgrind is highly praised, let's try
   that.  Strange, it works in Valgrind.  Hmm.
5. Actually read what Valgrind is telling you.  (This is where I didn't do my part.)  It
   flags you with errors such as "Invalid write of size 1" along with a trace of the
   various labels/symbols where this shows up.  Look for possible errors and adjust as
   necessary.
6. In this case, it was pointing me to an invocation of `memcpy()` in the `hashtable_put`
   function of `hashtable.c`.  The subtle hint is that I was passing the first argument
   to memcpy using the address-of operator `&`, which caused the corruption.
7. When I fixed that, Valgrind no longer complained.

The moral of the story:

- Don't ignore feedback from the tools.  No news is [usually] good news, so if Valgrind
  spits out lots of info their is an increased likelihood of a problem.
- Dynamic memory allocation bugs are subtle (*dynamic* in the true sense of the word)
  and can be affected by many variables.  Valgrind puts things in the middle of your
  program and the memory library so it knows what's going on, so I think these affected
  the program's operation somehow.

The commit that has so far fixed the issue:

http://code.seanwoods.com/reynard.fossil.cgi/ci/bd6a5a23c1?sbs=0

Comment: Good job fixing your own problem. I also successfully compiled and ran your code (with a few fixes to get rid of warnings) with the comments around your `main()` function removed, so that would have been another clue that the problem was elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, I too ran into the issue that you pointed in my own code. I could not catch your solution though... I went through thee code and following point is unclear: What is the relation between calling memcopy() and malloc()? I see absolutely no relation. I'm surely missing out something very subtle.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
As we have almost no idea what your struct o looks like and what datatype `o->data` should be, we can only speculae what you're trying to do.

Please specify the `o` struct definition, so we can help.

Comment: Almost certainly wrong. If you were allocating `char` pointers, you'd be storing the result in a `char **`, not a `char *`, although admittedly without seeing a full example it's impossible to tell what type `o->data` is, but his code is at least consistent, and yours isn't.

Comment: I have to say i've apparently been sloppy at reading. My mistake.
The type of the property `o->data` should be given to fully recommend what he's trying to do. My guess was that he's trying to save a string. But looking at his code again would suggest he was trying to do something else... I will edit my post.

Comment: The updated answer would be better as a comment.  You should be able to delete your own answers if you want to remove the downvotes here